ERROR in [eslint] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'references') Occurred while linting
I am new to work with vue. I have used @vue-flow/core to use a custom edge with button component. But while running the npm run build/serve, I am getting this error:

ERROR in [eslint] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'references') Occurred while linting

Below is the code for the component "EdgeWithButton.vue".
<script setup>
import { BaseEdge, EdgeLabelRenderer, getBezierPath } from "@vue-flow/core";
import { computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  sourceX: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  sourceY: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  targetX: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  targetY: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  sourcePosition: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  targetPosition: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  markerEnd: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  style: {
    type: Object,
    required: false,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  data: {
    type: Object,
    required: false,
  },
});

const path = computed(() => getBezierPath(props));
</script>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    removeEdgeAndJoins() {
      const edgeAndJoins = {
        id: this.id,
        joinId: this.data.joinId,
      };
      this.$emit("removeEdgeAndJoins", edgeAndJoins);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <!-- You can use the `BaseEdge` component to create your own custom edge more easily -->
  <BaseEdge :id="id" :style="style" :path="path[0]" :marker-end="markerEnd" />

  <!-- Use the `EdgeLabelRenderer` to escape the SVG world of edges and render your own custom label in a `<div>` ctx -->
  <EdgeLabelRenderer>
    <div
      :style="{
        pointerEvents: 'all',
        position: 'absolute',
        transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${path[1]}px,${path[2]}px)`,
      }"
      class="rectangle"
    >
      {{ label }}
      <button class="delete-btn" @click="removeEdgeAndJoins()">x</button>
    </div>
  </EdgeLabelRenderer>
</template>
<style>
/* Style for the rectangle div */
.rectangle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* Style for the delete button */
.delete-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 50%px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

I have tried adding "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true in the config.
"env": {
      "node": true,
      "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true
    },

But I am getting same error.

Do you have references somewhere in your code? ESlint should give you the file and the line where the issue happens. Also what's your ESlint settings?
